# Is there a good wrapper around ILGenerator?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, ilgenerator

I'm using System.Reflection.Emit for a while now, and find it (who don't?) as painful as bug prone.

Do you know if there is a good wrapper around the IL Generator, something that I can rely on to emit IL in a more safe and easier manner than with playing directly with SRE?

**Edit:**

I know that manipulating expression trees is definitively easier and safer than emitting IL directly, but they also have some constraints right now. I can't create code blocs, use loops, declare and work with several locals, etc. We need to wait until .NET 4 comes out :)

Moreover, I'm dealing with a code base which already relies on SRE.

Obviously, ILGenerator do everything I need. But I would appreciate more assistance when manipulating it. When I'm referring to a ILGenerator wrapper, which remains at a pretty low level, I think about something which could provide methods like:

```
// Performs a virtual or direct call on the method, depending if it is a 
// virtual or a static one.
Call(MethodInfo methodInfo)

// Pushes the default value of the type on the stack, then emit 
// the Ret opcode.
ReturnDefault(Type type)

// Test the object type to emit the corresponding push 
// opcode (Ldstr, Ldc_I*, Ldc_R*, etc.)
LoadConstant(object o)
```

It's really 3 naive examples, but it could be enough to demonstrate what I expect. We can see that as a set of extension methods, but it could be nice to have support for conditional statements and loops like in [RunSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/runsharp.aspx). In fact, RunSharp is pretty close that what I want, but it abstracts the ILGenerator too much and doesn't expose all its functionality.

I can't remember where, but I already saw such an helper in an open source project.

Comment: You haven't specified what it is that ILGenerator doesn't do, and what a 'good' wrapper would do.

Comment: That is a valid point ; I updated the question to provide more detail.

Comment: Actually, as Expressions are lambda expressions, you should be able to use looping, implemented as recursion + Y operator.

Comment: What do you call Y operator ?

Comment: I think it's called Y *combinator* — google it.

Comment: The answer to this question is resoundingly SIGIL! https://github.com/kevin-montrose/Sigil and a great sample on it https://gist.github.com/bretcope/a9dea0c5c67b0bc051c8

Answer (score 6):

If you're using .NET 3.5, you may find using Expression Trees to be more reasonable. It entirely depends on what you're doing - and it can still be quite painful - but it's certainly another option to be aware of.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still with .NET 2.0. I could use Mono implementation of Expression class, but expression trees are not able to handle what I aim to do ( code blocs, several local allocations, etc.)

Comment: Extension Trees are not useful when implementing complex types. Only when working with methods.

Answer (score 4):

[updated]: I thought of the name ;-p [RunSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/runsharp.aspx). I can't vouch for it, but it might be what you need.

However; what do you need to generate? [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) is one option. For creating methods, you might find that you can do a lot more than you expect with the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) class in .NET 3.5 (after compiling it to a typed delegate via Expression.Lambda/Compile.

Comment: I am aware of RunSharp, and I was looking for something like that which deals at a lower level. I prefer to stay away from CodeDom, even if it is a good solution in many cases. I'm stuck with DynamicMethods most of the time.

Comment: OK; minor thought, but you might have included this (and your 2.0 requirement) in the original question... Re "lower level" - what sort of level (between RunSharp and ILGenerator) are you looking for?

Comment: You are right, I added some more info in the original question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)

> Cecil is a library written by [Jb Evain](http://evain.net/blog/)
>   to generate
>   and inspect programs and libraries in
>   the ECMA CIL format. It has full
>   support for generics, and support some
>   debugging symbol format.